# Using spring boot, how to ignore the body of a POST request and use the response of a GET endpoint instead

Tags: java, spring-boot, mule

How can I call a `GET` endpoint from within a `POST` endpoint of the same application? And use the result of the `GET` endpoint in place of the body of the `POST` request.

Comment: Are you asking about Mule or Spring-Boot?

Answer (score 0):

In your POST endpoint, you can call the other endpoint this way:

```
@RequestMapping("value = "/yourPostEndpoint", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void postThis(HttpServletRequest request) {
    String url = request.getRequestURL().toString();
    String relativeGETUrl = url+"/yourGetEndpoint"; 
    String getEndpointResponse = new RestTemplate().getForObject(relativeGETUrl, String.class);

    // Do whatever you want to do with the get response

}
```

Then use whatever was returned by the endpoint to do your processing.